# what is this django admin search control called?

Tags: django, django-admin

I saw these cool filters for search on django admin.  Does anyone know what these are called?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is *not* the standard Django admin layout. It looks the [django-suit](http://djangosuit.com/) package. The filters you are referring to are the [list_filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) fields positioned and displayed differently.

Comment: Also Django-select2 is a Django integration of Select2. And Select2 is the jQuery replacement for select boxes.